# How to find count of specific column from JSON data using SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column which stores data in JSON format. Now I need to find count of specific attribute from all rows using same column.

```
Column Name: LogDetails
Data Format : {"ORDER_STATUS":"SUCCESS","ORDER_TYPE":"ODSP","ORDER_DATE":"27/03/2021","ORDER_POLLING":"\nCOUNTRY : RUSSIA, PO_ACCEPTED_STATE : Success"}
```

Here I need to find count where all ORDER_STATUS is SUCCESS.

How can we process it using SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

Below Query worked on POSTGRES:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE ORDER_STATUS::json->>'ORDER_STATUS' = 'SUCCESS'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you can use `JSON_VALUE`

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable t
WHERE JSON_VALUE(t.LogDetails, '$.ORDER_STATUS') = 'SUCCESS';
```